# Потокобезопасная коллекция для Parallel.For

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Какой список выбрать для `Parallel.For`? Например, в коллекции 1000 элементов. Хочу чтобы каждый поток брал по 10 элементов. Какую коллекцию использовать для этого?

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(); // В lst 1000 данных
Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, i) =>
    {

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос заключается в том, как обеспечить, чтобы каждый поток брал определённое количество элементов подряд, то для этого существует следующий стандартный подход:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, lst.Count, 10), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        // Используем элементы
        // lst[i]
    }
});
```

Метод [Partitioner.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create(v=vs.110).aspx) разбивает последовательность на диапазоны. В использованной перегрузке указан размер диапазона (10).

Коллекция при этом может быть любой, реализующей интерфейс [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), чтобы можно было обращаться к элементам по индексу.